# Deriving simple equation for volume and pressure, adiabatic exponent

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

> I have
>
> $$VT^\frac{f}{2}=\text{constant}\tag1$$
>
> and
>
> $$V^{\gamma}P=\text{constant}.\tag2$$
>
> Where $V=\text{volume}, \ P=\text{pressure} , \ T=\text{temperature},$
>   $f=\text{number of degrees of freedom per molecule}$ and
>   $\gamma=\frac{f+2}{f}.$
>
> I want to derive $(2)$ from $(1)$

Using the ideal gaslaw I have $T=\frac{PV}{Nk}$, where $N$ and $k$ are constant. Plugging this into $(1)$ I get

$$V\left(\frac{PV}{Nk}\right)^{\frac{f}{2}}=\frac{V^\frac{f+2}{2}P}{\text{constant}}=\text{constant},$$

and a constant times a constant is constant so finally

$$VT^{\frac{f}{2}}=V^{\frac{f+2}{2}}P=\text{constant}.$$

However my exponent is off, the denominator in the exponent should be $f$ but I get $2$. What am I missing?

Comment: Please state reason for downvote.

Comment: Seems to be a very 'silly' question; if not question, atleast your response to my answer is not genuine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not put $P^{f/2}$ after the first step. From there you will get the right answer (then you will take both sides of the equation to the 2/f power).

Comment: Please see my response to the answer above, from Tojrah.

Comment: @Parseval You asked what you are missing, you want the whole rest of the derivation worked out? I edited with the next step.

Answer (score 1):

$$V\bigg(\frac  {PV}{Nk} \bigg)^{f/2}=\frac{P^{f/2} V^{1+f/2}}{constant}$$

Comment: $P$ is not supposed to have any exponent in the final answer.